# Display Model Property in View

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I was wondering how I could display my model.property in my View without the model variable being of type IEnumerable, in the view; and also, what should I use in my controller instead of SingleOrDefault to show each row of the specific property?

Here is the code:

Model - Roles.cs

```
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedName { get; set; }
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    public int FunctionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FunctionId")]
    public Functions Functions { get; set; }
```

Model -Function.cs

```
[Key]
    public int FunctionId { get; set; }
    public string FunctionName { get; set; }
    public bool CanEdit { get; set; }
    public bool CanAdd { get; set; }
    public bool CanDel { get; set; }
    public bool CanView { get; set; }
```

Controller - RolesController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var aspNetRoles = await _context.AspNetRoles.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (aspNetRoles == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["FunctionId"] = new SelectList(_context.Functions, "FunctionId", "FunctionId", aspNetRoles.FunctionId);
        return View(aspNetRoles);
    }
```

And then what I am trying to get for my View
Role/Edit.cshtml

```
<div class="flex-row col-8">
        @foreach(var item in Model //what to do?)
             {
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Functions.FunctionName) 
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Functions.CanAdd"  />  
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Functions.CanEdit" /> 
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Functions.CanDel"  />  
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Functions.CanView" />    
             }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly which model and which property are you trying to display in the view?

Comment: Hey sorry about that, it is the role.cs model for the foreign key properties (canadd, canedit, candel, canview). I added the Functions model as well.Thanks!

Comment: _what should I use in my controller instead of SingleOrDefault to show each row of the specific property?_ are you looking for each `Role` with a `Functions` enabled e.g. all `Roles` with `CanEdit == true`?

Comment: _I was wondering how I could display my model.property in my View without the model variable being of type IEnumerable, in the view_ just remove the `@foreach` loop since you don't have a collection to iterate.

Comment: I need it so all functions, enabled or disabled, appear. What it is supposed to be is a edit screen that allows an admin to give permissions to user through a UI. So if the admin clicks edit permissions for a Role, it shows all the functions that that admin may or may not allow for a given role.